# Vim replace line with captured word

Tags: regex, vim

Using vim, I want to replace

```
if(strncmp(name, "STR1", 3) == 0)
if(strncmp(name, "STR2", 4) == 0)
...
if(strncmp(name, "STR100", 2) == 0)
```

in the entire file with

```
if(!strncmp(name, "STR1", 3))
if(!strncmp(name, "STR2", 4))
...
if(!strncmp(name, "STR100", 2))
```

I tried:

```
:%s/if(strncmp(.*) == 0)/if(!strncmp(\1))/g
```

However the inside of the parentheses is not captured. Where is this discussed in the manual?

Comment: I hope these lines all have a regular format to them--regex can't generally parse C source code if you have arbitrary expressions inside of these calls to `strcmp`. First section should be `if(strcmp(\(.*\)) == 0)`--you need a capture group. Toss in `if (strcmp(foo(), bar()) == 0)` and it breaks (this could be handled but it just delays the inevitable need for a parser).

Comment: worked like butter, heart-warming thank you!

Comment: If the answer worked please do accept it by clicking the check mark below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(strncmp(\(.*\)) == 0)` should do the trick--note the `\(.*\)` capture group. Full command:

```
:%s/if(strncmp(\(.*\)) == 0)/if(!strncmp(\1))/g
```

If you have arbitrary expressions inside your `strncmp`s, this won't work and you'll need either progressively more complex patterns to handle each edge case or a parser. But the above regex is fine if your file is in an expected format.